# Can not update configurable products, price of simples suddenly become 0,00

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, products, magento2.1.0

### Preconditions

- Magento 2.1
- Nginx
- PHP 7.0.9
- Memcached
- Redis Server

### Steps to reproduce

1. Add a new configurable product
2. Create the simple products while creating the configurable product
3. Save the product
4. Open the configurable product again
5. Upload images or change any other data
6. Save the product

### Expected result

Configurable product gets updated.

Simple products related with the configurable product should stay the same

### Actual result

The simple products suddenly have the price of 0

### What has been done allready

- I did a clean install of Magento
- I setup a new server with Magento
- Reported the bug with Magento, but they cannot reproduce the error https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5973

Is there anyone else that stumbled uppon this bug? And if so how did you solve it.

If you did not solve it can we reported the error together or fix it together?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else running into this, this is language/currency related (sadly).

Quick fix is to set the admin language to us_US (as said in above issue 5973)

This problem is also related to "Custom options save wrong price values after editing #6342" on the Magento Forums. I have this problem in Magento 2.1.2 and though I have found a solution for the custom options I don't yet have one for the simple prices related to the configurable product.